# Thread-Safe Code Becomes Too Clumsy?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I never actually wrote a multithreading application.

In the few times I did write one, it seems to me thread-safety gets too clumsy too quickly.

The internet is full of tutorials about thread-safety general technique, but there's not much I found about real world programing issues.

for example, taking this simple code, (does nothing usable)

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    void Something()
    {
        sb.AppendLine("Numbers!");
        int oldLength = sb.Length;
        int i = 0;
        while (sb.Length < 500 + oldLength)
        {
            sb.Append((++i).ToString());
            //something slow
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                sb.Append("!");
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
    }
```

Now assuming I want to run this method from multiple threads, all writing to the same string builder.

I want them to write to the same target together, so it's possible that there will be one line from one thread, and right after it another line from another thread, and then the next line back from the first thread.

**for the sake of the conversation, let's assume it's ok even if there a line from one thread in the *middle* of another line**

And here's the code:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    object sbLocker = new object();
    void SomethingSafe()
    {
        int oldLength;
        int length;

        lock (sbLocker)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("Numbers!");
            oldLength = sb.Length;
            length = oldLength;
        }


        int i = 0;

        while (length < 500 + oldLength)
        {
            lock (sbLocker)
                sb.Append((++i).ToString());

            //something slow
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                lock (sbLocker)
                    sb.Append("(EVEN)");
            }

            lock (sbLocker)
            {
                sb.AppendLine();
                length = sb.Length;
            }
        }
    }
```

So exhausting and unreadable...

Isn't there any way to tell the compiler to just simply lock sbLocker every time there's any access to sb?

Why my code need to be so clumsy for such a simple rule? There's no much thinking into this specific, yet very usable, technique. Can it be done anyway easier?

We can't even inherit StringBuilder since it's sealed.

Of Course, one can go ahead and wrap the whole class:

```
public class SafeStringBuilder
{
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    object locker = new object();
    public void Append(string s)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            sb.Append(s);
        }
    }

    //................
}
```

but this is just crazy... as there are so many different classes we are using.

Any idea how to make thread safe practice in this sense?

I know that for creating the exact same result there might be a simpler solution... but this is just an example. I'm pretty sure I've encountered similar problems without any readable solution possible.

Comment: FYI, there *are* [concurrent collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) which make certain cases much simpler. Regarding a `StringBuilder` specifically, reading/writing to an actively changing string doesn't seem that useful. You as the developer probably need to dictate when you want to block and when you don't for it to be useful.

Comment: This is why 1. We build libs and frameworks to reuse and 2. We avoid sharing data between threads.

Comment: I might be missing something, but it looks like you do not need the lock when you do sb.Append or sb.AppendLine. That is, if you do not care about the order in which the elements are written to the string builder. You do not have to check sb.Length either, you can simply use for (int i = 0; i++ i<500) instead of while (length < 500 + oldLength)

Comment: +! on the sharing data comment.  *yes* you could share data between threads and have multiple threads do work.  But, they'd be waiting on each other at times--which kind of defeats the purpose of multi threading.

Comment: @PeterRitchie - I can't see how you can avoid sharing data in any application

Comment: @Letterman You can avoid sharing data during parallel operations.  see Map/Reduce as an example.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I have an optimization engine which get all kind of Jobs to optimize+execute. The engine might invoke the jobs from multiple threads. the jobs at their turn, can add more jobs backto the engine. can i avoid making the engine thread-safe?

Comment: @Letterman if you use Message Passing, you can avoid shared data and avoid much work on making code "thread safe".  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing

Comment: @PeterRitchie How can it be done in C#? is that a popular technique? Googling it brought weird results :O

Comment: @PeterRitchie But thank you a lot any way =o

Comment: Message passing is really just making copies of the data (the message) and passing that into the logic that processes it.  There should be a few questions related to that here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I see. but if my engine, for example, has a method `AddJob`, this method must be thread safe. otherwise i'm accessing members of the class from different threads in an unsafe manner.

Comment: @Letterman A method that does not use shared state is thread-safe.  So, yes it "must be thread safe", but the work involved in making it thread-safe is the design decision to use message-passing.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in that writing threadsafe code is potentially infinitely more complicated than writing single threaded code. It is something that probably should be avoided wherever it isn't necessary.

You are incorrect in assuming that it can't be written in a readable fashion. Unfortunately, it is really hard to make this into an answer, and the best I can do is offer some guidelines:

1. Find logical places for divisions in threads. Something like building a common string  doesn't really make sense as it won't speed up what you're doing. In order for multi-threading to make sense, there has to be some part that can be done independently (or mostly independently) of other pieces of the program. Good examples include matrix multiplication and a server responding to client requests. Chances are that if you are multi-threading something that isn't a good fit for multi-threading, it will be exceptionally difficult to write elegant code.
2. Wherever data sharing is necessary, attempt to follow the model: lock, access/alter, unlock.
3. Follow a hierarchy for locking order.
4. Avoid directly sharing data through duplication, message passing, etc. wherever possible.
5. Hide the locking from as much of the rest of the code as much as possible. Give them functions that handle the shared data wherever possible.

Unfortunately, writing elegant multi-threaded code is more something that you perfect over years of effort than something that can be taught in a stack overflow question, but hopefully this answer sheds some light.

Comment: thank you. any good tutorial out there though? i'm sure it's not that mystical that it cannot be learn without a few years passing by..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177488/c-sharp-threading the top answer there has about 35 upvotes so that should be a pretty decent tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Some framework classes provide you with the thread-safe wrappers that you can use. For example, you can create a `StringWriter` over the StringBuilder, and then use TextWriter.Synchronized to get a thread-safe wrapper that can be accessed simultaneously from several threads.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var tw = new StringWriter(sb);

var threadSafeWriter = TextWriter.Synchronized(tw);

threadSafeWriter.Write("Hello");
threadSafeWriter.WriteLine(" world");
```

And, there also thread-safe concurrent collections that can be handy.

If you really want "a compiler to lock object every time it is accessed" without writing custom wrapper for each type, you can use some library, like Castle.Proxy, to generate wrappers at runtime. However, in non-trivial scenarios, when multiple object accesses should be performed atomically, this would not produce the results you need.

Comment: is that better than `StringBuilder SafeSb { get { lock (locker) return sb; } }` ?

Comment: StringBuilder, returned by this property would not be thread-safe, and if several threads do `SafeSb.Append(...)` , data corruption may occur

Comment: why is that? calling .Append is going through the getter. is it not?

Comment: Getter will return a reference to an object. After reference is returned, lock will be released. And Append will be invoked after reference is returned.